# destroy and relaunch application after gps enable checking

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gps

Hi am running with an issue. I have a gps checking function on my splash screen where after checking my gps connectivity if its state is null it shows an alert.I want to destroy and restart my application after the button click of alert box. Kindly help. here is my code

Geolocationfinder class

```
package com.driverapp.inis.zuber;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GeoLocationFinder {
    private static final String TAG = "GeoLocationFinder";
    Timer locationTimer;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final int min_update_time = 3000; // in msec
    private static final int min_distance_for_update = 10; // in meters
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled = Boolean.FALSE;
    boolean network_enabled = Boolean.FALSE;
    private AlertDialogManager alert;
    Context ctx;


    public boolean getLocation(Context ctx, LocationResult result) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        locationResult = result;

        if (locationManager == null) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        try {
            gps_enabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           /* alert = new AlertDialogManager();
            alert.showAlertDialog(ctx, "Error", "GPS enabled exception:", false);*/
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS enabled exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Network enabled exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            alert = new AlertDialogManager();
            alert.showAlertDialog(ctx, "Error", "Please Check Your GPS Connection and Try Again", false);
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, min_update_time,
                    min_distance_for_update, locationListenerGps);
        }

        if (network_enabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, min_update_time,
                    min_distance_for_update, locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        locationTimer = new Timer();
        locationTimer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 2000);
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationTimer.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS provider disabled" + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS provider enabled" + provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS status changed");

        }
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationTimer.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Network provider disabled. " + provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Network provider enabled. " + provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Network status changed.");

        }
    };

    private class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled) {
                gps_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (network_enabled) {
                net_loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
                if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime()) {
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                } else {
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                }
                return;
            }

            if (gps_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }

            if (net_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            else {
                locationResult.gotLocation(null);
            }

        }

    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Splashscreen class

```
package com.driverapp.inis.zuber;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import Connectivity_manager.Internet_CheckingActivity;



public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "SplashScreenActivity";
    private Location newLocation = null;
    private AlertDialogManager alert;
    private Internet_CheckingActivity chckInternt;
    private  GeoLocationFinder geoLocationFinder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        chckInternt = new Internet_CheckingActivity(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //  setupLocation();
        if (chckInternt.isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
            setupLocation();
        }
        else
        {
            alert.showAlertDialog(Splashscreen.this, "Error", "Please Check Your Internet Connection", false);
        }


    }
    /** Method for checking the current lat log values. */
    private void setupLocation() {
        GeoLocationFinder.LocationResult locationResult = new GeoLocationFinder.LocationResult() {

            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {

                    newLocation = new Location(location);
                    newLocation.set(location);

                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Got coordinates, congratulations. Longitude = "
                                    + newLocation.getLongitude() + " Latitude = "
                                    + newLocation.getLatitude());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else{
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                alert.showAlertDialog(Splashscreen.this, "Check Your GPS", "Restart your Application", false);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        geoLocationFinder = new GeoLocationFinder();
        geoLocationFinder.getLocation(this,locationResult);
    }
}
```

AlertDialogManager class

```
package com.driverapp.inis.zuber;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;

public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */

     public int setOk = 0;
     public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
   //     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        AlertDialog.Builder  alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);


        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.setCancelable(Boolean.FALSE);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /*Aler used for the delete in sheet details*/

    public void showAlertDialogDelete(final Context context, String title, String message,
                                Boolean status) {
        //     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        AlertDialog.Builder  alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);


        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent in = new Intent(context, Splashscreen.class);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.setCancelable(Boolean.FALSE);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the code of `AlertDialogManager` class.

Comment: have edited kindly help me out of problem @PrerakSola

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in `OnClick()` method of the Positive buton:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Splashscreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

context.startActivity(intent);
```

It will clear the activity stack of your application and launch `Splashscreen` activity.

Comment: getting an error "cannot resolve getApplicationContext()"

Comment: Try `this` instead of `getApplicationContext`.

Comment: "cannot resolve constructor" after trying this and even am getting "cannot resolve startactivity"  @Prerak Sola

Comment: Extend your `Splashscreen` activity to `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: extended but Still the same.. @Prerak Sola

Comment: Oh..!! my bad. I read the wrong lines. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you the error had gone but the application is not killing and relaunching.

Comment: Are you sure? Because, you are relaunching the same activity, so you will not see the transition of killing the app and launching it. Add some logs and see if you get hem twice or not.